# How do you make linked text act as if it is normal text?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a blur effect on hover using css and jquery. When you hover over one of the pieces of text, certain parts of the css are applied to siblings using jquery. If you look at the [link](http://tragicclothing.co.uk/del.html) the "Music" text is not hyperlinked and acts how I want, when hovered. But the rest are linked and I want them to act like "Music" when they are hyperlinked.

**CSS:**

```
.blur {
text-decoration: none;
color: #339;
-webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
-moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
transition: 400ms ease 100ms;

}  

.textshadow {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
outline: 0 none;
-webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
-moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
transition: 400ms ease 100ms; }  
.out {
text-shadow: 0 0 4px #339;}


a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
opacity:none;
}
```

Comment: If you want them to all act the same you can just change the `<th width="164" class="blur" scope="col"><a href=""></a>Music</th>` to  `<th width="164" class="blur" scope="col"><a href="">Music</a></th>`, could you not?

Comment: define `act like`. Not sure why you can't just write same css rules for `th` as `th a`

Comment: Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8nq/) for your issue.

Comment: @tehsockz No I want the others to work as if they have not been hyperlinked. Not the other way round :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Hi, I don't think you understood the question. You can clearly see in this fiddle that the other texts are not bluring like the "Music" text. And that is what I am after :)

Comment: they all act the same, except for the cursor. you can add a{ cursor: default; text-decoration:none; } to your css (you don't need to redefine text-decoration: none; for visited/hover/active)

Comment: Yes, I made that initial fiddle just to separate the important parts of the HTML/JS/CSS so people can more clearly see it. `=]`

Comment: why is the .blur class set to the th element instead of the a element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.blur').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().children().addClass('out textshadow');
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('out textshadow');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8nq/1/) - all texts are hyperlinked.

---

Or you can keep the same JS (without `.children()`) and edit the CSS selectors:

`.blur` to `.blur a`
`.textshadow` to `.textshadow a`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8nq/2/)

Comment: Thats so wierd. I tried changind the css to that and it didn't work!

Comment: Ensure to restore the JS to the version w/o `.children` if using the CSS one. Otherwise the JS one will do fine as well. `=]`

Comment: oh wait now if you look at my link. It goes immediately back to the beginning when hovered out instead of fading? any ideas :)

Comment: @maxmitch The problem is with the JS solution right, it doesn't happen with the CSS one. To fix the JS one, simply move the `transition` property to a separate rule that doesn't get removed - here's the fixed and commented [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8nq/5/).